# How to Successfully and Efficiently Install SQLite3 in Electron-Forge?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sqlite, electron, electron-forge

How can I install and run sqlite3 with the electron-forge app?
Whenever I try to create a new project and add sqlite3, there are always missing dependencies and errors.

I've tried installing it with `npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source`, but after that, when I start the application it breaks and reports missing dependencies all over the place. After installing them it works, but the package and make are broken with the following error:

```
> electron-forge package

√ Checking your system
√ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\dbnavigator.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\dbnavigator.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\encodings.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\encodings.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\jsLibraryMappings.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\jsLibraryMappings.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\markdown-navigator\profiles_settings.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\markdown-navigator\profiles_settings.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\markdown-navigator.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\markdown-navigator.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\misc.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\misc.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\modules.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\modules.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\vcs.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\vcs.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\watcherTasks.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\watcherTasks.xml resulted in a MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
Failed to compile file: C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\workspace.xml
Compiling C:\Users\neman\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\rentacar-manager-win32-x64\resources\app\.idea\workspace.xml resulted in a    MIME type of application/xml, which we don't know how to handle
√ Compiling Application
√ Preparing native dependencies: 1 / 1
√ Packaging Application
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
npm install --save-dev electron-prebuilt
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`

I have tried, that worked.
But after rebuild, my electron version change to v1.1+，and I can't use "async" because node version is lower then 7.0。
If you don't care whether to use ES7，try this way.

Comment: I've moved away from the electron-forge, thus cannot try it.

Comment: What did you end up using in place of electron-forge?